# send select Cell in tableview and send to another screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

Hi I'm creating an app related to iOS. This app display number of people in tableview. Each cell in tableview shows the name of the person and detail of the person also each person have audio file attached. when i select the any cell and hit the shortlist button i want to display this information into another screen and email the selected cell to anyone. So i want to show name, detail, and the audio file into another screen. i am using swift language and Xcode 7. Please help me to find answer.

Comment: check this tutorial https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/

Answer (score 0):

Please implement TableView Delegate method below, When you select a cell this method will invoke. There you can instantiate new ViewController where you want to display the data.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. can you please explain me a bit more in detail with little code. i am new in swift thanks

Comment: Sure, we have some delegate methods check 'UITableViewDelegate' I'll explain that

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to find out what cell was selected. Using the **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** function.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

}
```

After you have found out what row was selected you can then segue into the next view controller but before this is done you will have to call the **prepareForSegue** function which allows the variables to be passed into the view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
{

}
```

Comment: thanks very much for your quick reply let me try thanks again .

Answer (score 0):

Use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method current `ViewController`,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let sample = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerIdentifierName") as! ViewControllerB

            sample.mainArray =  yourArrayName.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(sample, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

If you send data to Another `ViewControllerB` declare the variable mainArray,

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerB: UIViewController {

    var mainArray = NSMutableArray()

}
```

The above example is one way, you will declare the variable's to pass many data `tableview` `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to Another `ViewController`,

hope its helpful

Comment: thanks very much this is working for me thanks againg